# How to mark a paragraph or sentence with a tag/markets in OpenXML documents

Tags: ms-office, powerpoint, openxml, docx, xliff

I am using okapi framework (http://okapi.sourceforge.net/) to generate a Xliff file for a translatable source unit. (Eg: A .docx or .pptx source file). Okapi basically unzips the .docx files, iterates over translatable content and generates a xliff file.

I was curious to know if Office 2007+ suite has some functionality, where in I can mark a sentence or a paragraph with a marker or tag (this marker and tag should not change any content of the doc itself and must be invisible when I print the document), which I can use later while generating Xliff by going through the tagged/marked sentence as non translatable.

I am new to OpenXML format and tools and wasn't sure such a feature exists and how to use it.

Comment: There's nothing built-in for that, but you might approach it by inserting e.g. a thin space (U+2009) or no-width space (U+200B).  Or by adding a tag or tags indicating the starting/ending positions of the text within the shape's text range.

Answer (score 0):

Okapi Rainbow has a feature that you can use to exclude strings from translation, at least for Word and Excel documents: you can create a new filter configuration that is based on the built-in `okf-openxml` filter and exclude certain styles (for Word) or colours (for Excel). Then you only have to define these styles or colours in your document and mark any text in Word or Excel that should not be translated in that style or colour.

Unfortunately there is no similar feature for Powerpoint. :-(